# WinForm CheckListBox problem with ItemCheck event

Tags: vb.net, winforms

When the checked state of a check box change, I would like to know what the new value is. 
his is what I am doing:

```
Friend WithEvents clstTask As System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox

Private Sub clstTask_ItemCheck(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ItemCheckEventArgs) Handles clstTask.ItemCheck
    Dim SelectedCheckState As CheckState = clstTask.GetItemCheckState(clstTask.SelectedIndex)
End Sub
```

However, the value of the SelectedCheckState variable is not accuratley reflecting the new state. I think it is showing the current state before the click, as if this were a "Before_CheckChanged" event handler.

The Check box is a 3 state check box, (Checked, UnChecked, Undetermined). Do I have to write ugly code that assumes that if the CheckState returned is state "X" that the CURRENT state must be Y?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ItemCheckEventArgs exposes properties CurrentValue and NewValue.

Comment: Darn. I remember it when I see it. Figured I missed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check out ItemCheckEventArgs.NewValue and ItemCheckEventArgs.CurrentValue.   This is why that parameter is there ;)